# How to shape shadows in React Native for android?

Tags: react-native

**Package used:** [react-native-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow)

**Problem:** How to shape the shadow if the view is circular-shaped? I have used Avatar and want shadow behind it with the same shape.

**Code Used:**

```
<BoxShadow setting={{
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    color: "#000",
    radius: 20,
    opacity: 0.1,
    x: 2,
    y: 3,
    style: { marginVertical: 7 }
}}>
    <Avatar size={90} overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#bf1e2e' }} rounded title="GS" onPress={() => console.log("Works!")} activeOpacity={0.7} />
</BoxShadow>
```

**Solution Tried:** I tried making radius 44, 48 but gives error after 50 If someone can give a reason would be great.

**Current Output:**
[Click Here: Shadow Shape is rectangular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WcJR.png)

**Expected Output:**
[Click Here: Shadow Shape is circular and blurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDUaJ.png)

Comment: Can you keep radius: 45 & Avatar size={80}. Or let me know which module of Avatar you'd used here.

Comment: Keeping radius 45 just makes it close to round shape but not a perfect round shape & Avatar size={80} will reduce its size nothing else. I have used Avatar in "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2" package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add and try this in your code:

```
<BoxShadow
  setting={{
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    border: 10,   //Add this
    color: '#8d1622',
    radius: 45,   //Change here
    opacity: 1,   //Change here
    x: 0,   //Change here
    y: 0,   //Change here
    style: { marginVertical: 7 },
  }}>
  <Avatar
    size={90}
    overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#bf1e2e' }}
    rounded
    title="GS"
    onPress={() => console.log('Works!')}
    activeOpacity={0.7}
  />
</BoxShadow>
```

Comment: welcome. Please up-Vote my answer if you find your solution.

Comment: I tried Reputation should be more then 15.

Comment: No worries. wish you all the best for future.